# why PhantomReference does not work?

Tags: java, phantom-reference

Demo code:

```
import java.lang.ref.PhantomReference;
import java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Object test = new Object();
        ReferenceQueue<Object> q = new ReferenceQueue<Object>();
        PhantomReference<Object> p = new PhantomReference<Object>(test, q);
        Object lock = new Object();
        while (true) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                                 //q.poll() is null always,why?
                if (q.poll() != null) {
                    break;
                }
                //System.gc();
                lock.wait();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(1111111);
    }
}
```

I tested the code,but it always is dead loop.
The code (System.out.println(1111111);) can not execute,q.poll()  reurn null.

I think if test object is removed by GC,q.poll() will return p object,then break loop,but invoke this demo code,it is not like my thought

Edited:
I modify the demo code,it can work now.

```
import java.lang.ref.PhantomReference;
import java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Object test = new Object();
        ReferenceQueue<Object> q   = new ReferenceQueue<Object>();
        PhantomReference<Object> p = new PhantomReference<Object>(test, q);
        Object lock = new Object();
        while (true) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                if (q.poll() != null) {
                    break;
                }
                test = null; //it is important  
                System.gc();
                lock.wait(100);//should not lock.wait()
            }
        }
        System.out.println(1111111);
    }
}
```

AS sb says,the statement( test=null) is key.GC collect test object that assign null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that the `test` variable is still present means the GC will never collect the object it refers to... I believe JVMs don't collect anything that a local variable refers to even if the local variable is never referred to in the rest of the method.

(Also, it's not clear why you're using `lock.wait()` when nothing is calling `lock.pulse()`.)

Here's code which works for me:

```
import java.lang.Thread;
import java.lang.ref.PhantomReference;
import java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Object test = new Object();
        ReferenceQueue<Object> q = new ReferenceQueue<Object>();
        PhantomReference<Object> p = new PhantomReference<Object>(test, q);
        Object lock = new Object();
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Checking queue...");
            if (q.poll() != null) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("Still polling...");
            System.gc();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Interrupted!");
                break;
            }
            // Make the object garbage...
            test = null;
        }
        System.out.println("Finished.");
    }
}
```

Comment: It should lock.wait(100),i want to block thread for some time.

Comment: @boiledwater: Why do you prefer to use `lock.wait()` when nothing is ever going to pulse that monitor? Basically you're just trying to sleep - so why not use `Thread.sleep` like I did?

Comment: I just want to block thread for some time,no prefer ;lock.wait(100),Thread.sleep(100);I think them have the same funcation at here;pls:Thread.sleep() method does not release monitor lock that may be cause dead lock.So i usually use wait() method.

Comment: @boiledwater: You shouldn't usually "just need to sleep" in production code *anyway* - but in this case the *sole* purpose is to sleep, so bothering to acquire a lock and then wait on it, knowing that nothing is going to notify it, seems very odd to me. It means your code doesn't really communicate what you're trying to do, which is simply sleep.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
test = null;
```

before your while loop, so that the test object is eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: However, the GC may not be triggered for a very long time.